# Symfony2 Form Collection Field with Different Choices

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to dynamically generate a form based on information from the database.  Depending on the category page that I'm on, I need to display a list of select boxes, and each of those has a different set of options.  For example:

```
<select name="attributes[1]">
<option value="foo">bar</option
<option value="foo2">bar2</option
<option value="foo3">bar3</option
</select>

<select name="attributes[2]">
<option value="fiz">buzz</option
<option value="fiz2">buzz2</option
<option value="fiz3">buzz3</option
</select>
```

I understand that I have to use a FormEvent to add fields to the form based on database data.  However, I don't know how to add a collection field which contains different choices for each "member" of the collection.  Do I need to use subforms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to build a form that includes fields from another object. There's a section in The Symfony Book about embedded forms ([Embedded Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#embedded-forms)) and a nice, comprehensive entry in the CookBook ([How to Embed a Collection of Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)) covering even more complex topic.