# Symfony2 collection of choices different option for each elements

Tags: symfony

After several search and try I don't know how to solve my problem.

I found this: [Symfony2 Form Collection Field with Different Choices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25656509/symfony2-form-collection-field-with-different-choices) but solution was not given only a search trail and I didn't found how to adapt solution in my case.

I have Many to Many relation between Localization and Region, Many to Many relation between LOcalization and Department and Many to Many relation between Localization and City.

To create a localization i have this form:

```
class LocalizationType extends AbstractType{


private $manager;

public function __construct(ObjectManager $manager)
{
    $this->manager = $manager;
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){


    $builder->add('regions', CollectionType::class, array('entry_type' => ChoiceType::class,
                                                            'allow_add' => true,
                                                            'allow_delete' => true,
                                                            'required' => false,
                                                            'entry_options' => array(
                                                                'choices' => (array_key_exists('regions', $options['localization_value']) ? $options['localization_value']['regions'] : array('' => '')),
                                                                'multiple' => false,
                                                                'expanded' => false,
                                                                'attr' => array('class' => 'region input'),

                                                                ),
                                                            'data' => (array_key_exists('regions', $options['localization_data']) ? $options['localization_data']['regions'] : null),
                                                            ))
            ->add('departments', CollectionType::class, array('entry_type' => ChoiceType::class,
                                                                'allow_add' => true,
                                                                'allow_delete' => true,
                                                                'required' => false,
                                                                'entry_options' => array(
                                                                'choices' => (array_key_exists('departments', $options['localization_value']) ? $options['localization_value']['departments'] : array('' => '')),
                                                                    'multiple' => false,
                                                                    'expanded' => false,
                                                                    'attr' => array('class' => 'department input')
                                                                    ),
                                                                'data' => (array_key_exists('departments', $options['localization_data']) ? $options['localization_data']['departments'] : null),
                                                                ))
            ->add('cities', CollectionType::class, array('entry_type' => ChoiceType::class,
                                                            'allow_add' => true,
                                                            'allow_delete' => true,
                                                            'required' => false,
                                                            'entry_options' => array(
                                                                'choices' => (array_key_exists('cities', $options['localization_value']) ? $options['localization_value']['regions'] : array('' => '')),
                                                                'multiple' => false,
                                                                'expanded' => false,
                                                                'attr' => array('class' => 'city input')
                                                                ),
                                                            'data' => (array_key_exists('cities', $options['localization_data']) ? $options['localization_data']['cities'] : null),
                                                            ))
    ;

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event){

        $data = $event->getData();

        if(!empty($data['regions']) && is_array($data['regions'])){

            $regions = array();

            foreach($data['regions'] as $region){

                $regions[] = $region;

            }

            $data['regions'] = $this->manager->getRepository('LocalizationBundle:Region')->findRegionsForCreateEntity($regions);

        }

        if(!empty($data['departments']) && is_array($data['departments'])){

            $departments = array();

            foreach($data['departments'] as $department){

                $departments[] = $department;

            }

            $data['departments'] = $this->manager->getRepository('LocalizationBundle:Departments')->findDepartmentsForCreateEntity($departments);

        }

        if(!empty($data['cities']) && is_array($data['cities'])){

            $cities = array();

            foreach($data['cities'] as $city){

                $cities[] = $city;

            }

            $data['cities'] = $this->manager->getRepository('LocalizationBundle:City')->findCitiesForCreateEntity($cities);

        }

        $form = $event->getForm();

        $form->add('regions', CollectionType::class, array('entry_type' => ChoiceType::class,
                                                            'allow_add' => true,
                                                            'allow_delete' => true,
                                                            'required' => false,
                                                            'entry_options' => array(
                                                                'choices' => $data['regions'],
                                                                'multiple' => false,
                                                                'expanded' => false,
                                                                'attr' => array('class' => 'region input')
                                                                )
                                                            ));


                $form->add('departments', CollectionType::class, array('entry_type' => ChoiceType::class,
                                                                    'allow_add' => true,
                                                                    'allow_delete' => true,
                                                                    'required' => false,
                                                                    'entry_options' => array(
                                                                        'choices' => $data['departments'],
                                                                        'multiple' => false,
                                                                        'expanded' => false,
                                                                        'attr' => array('class' => 'department input')
                                                                        )
                                                                    ))
                ->add('cities', CollectionType::class, array('entry_type' => ChoiceType::class,
                                                                'allow_add' => true,
                                                                'allow_delete' => true,
                                                                'required' => false,
                                                                'entry_options' => array(
                                                                    'choices' => $data['cities'],
                                                                    'multiple' => false,
                                                                    'expanded' => false,
                                                                    'attr' => array('class' => 'city input')
                                                                    )
                                                                ))
    ;


    });

}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver){

    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => Localization::class,
        'localization_data' => array('regions' => '', 'departments' => '', 'cities' => ''),
        'localization_value' => array('regions' => '', 'departments' => '', 'cities' => ''),
    ));

}
```

I choose a ChoiceType empty because I have several City for example( more of 25k) so I prefer load few of them with AJAX in my view and render them in a select2, it works for add action but for edit action I have a problem I want each field of my collections have a different value.

To illustrate my story, I want this result:

```
<label>Region n°1</label>
<select id="" name="">
    <option value="foo1">bar1</option>
</select>

<label>Region n°2</label>
<select id="" name="">
    <option value="foo2">bar2</option>
</select>
```

And the result I have for the moment is:

```
<label>0</label>
<select id="" name="">
    <option value="foo1" selected="selected">bar1</option>
    <option value="foo2">bar2</option>
</select>

<label>1</label>
<select id="" name="">
    <option value="foo1">bar1</option>
    <option value="foo2" selected="selected">bar2</option>
</select>
```

To change label if I understand I need to create my own template, ok but to display only option selected and not others I think I need a FormEventListener on PRE_SET_DATA but I don't see how implement this. So if someone has a solution, I'll take it.

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question, after try with FormEventListener on PRE_SET_DATA, on POST_SET_DATA, or with a choice_loader it's seems to be impossible to do what i want with a Symfony way, but i don't well understand why. I feel back on Jquery way to remove option who are not selected with following code, i dislike but I don't see others solutions:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $.each($('.region'), function(i, val){

        $(val).find('option:not(:selected)').remove();

    })

    $.each($('.department'), function(i, val){

        $(val).find('option:not(:selected)').remove();

    })

    $.each($('.city'), function(i, val){

        $(val).find('option:not(:selected)').remove();

    })
</script>
```

I don't pass the topic as solved in case I'm wrong